# Quão obrigatórias são as normas NBR da ABNT? (Qual a natureza jurídica da ABNT?)

Tags: português-brasileiro, gramática, cultura, formalismo

O contexto da pergunta é especificamente relacionada à escritura de textos formais acadêmicos como dissertação de mestrado, tese de doutorado e artigos.  Mas também quero colocar a pergunta no contexto jurídico.

Se a ABNT fosse um mistério do poder executivo, as normas seriam obrigatórias, embora parte de legislação infra-legal e ainda sendo importante notar que "ninguém será obrigado a fazer ou deixar de fazer qualquer coisa em virtude de lei", que é inciso do quinto artigo constitucional.

Aderimos às normas ABNT meramente por convenção ou existe qualquer nível de obrigatoriedade nelas, seja legal ou cultural?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A adesão às normas ABNT é comum no Brasil, mas elas **não** são (universalmente) obrigatórias, como esclarece o próprio [website da ABNT](http://www.abnt.org.br/normalizacao/o-que-e/niveis-de-normalizacao):

> Normalmente são voluntárias, isto é, cabe aos agentes econômicos decidirem se as usam ou não como referência técnica para uma transação.
>
> *Exemplo: Normas da Associação Brasileira de Normas Técnicas (ABNT)*

E, naturalmente, como se tratam de normas nacionais brasileiras, elas não têm nenhum efeito direto fora do Brasil.

Contudo, organizações e instituições podem estabelecer a obrigatoriedade das normas da ABNT, e/ou de outras, para a elaboração de seus documentos. Muitas universidades, por exemplo, exigem a adesão às normas ABNT na elaboração de trabalhos de conclusão de curso (TCCs). Já para dissertações e teses, é também comum que, ou se dê liberdade ao candidato quanto à forma, ou que haja normas específicas da instituição.